# Really looking for a example/use case, when to use stages in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am really confused when stages are necessary in Azure DevOps.

Consider this code underneath, it works and build and deploys but does it one big implicit job with multiple tasks.
I could have made a build and deployment stage with possible multiple jobs, but does anyone have an example/use case when that would be useful?

```
  # ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 
    packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/*.zip'
```

Comment: I’m a bit confused about what you’re asking. Are you asking why use stages if could do it as one big job? I guess something to consider would be ‘dependsOn’. For example if you have a “build” and “deployment” stage your “deployment” stage would “dependOn” the “build” stage to be successful.

Comment: Hi OH.IO.Dev yes exactly that is what I’m asking that’s a great example and are there other reasons besides that? Thanks so much for your response

Comment: Did you start by looking at the documentation? It explains the use cases and provides examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's been helpful for my team to split our release pipeline into separate stages per deployment environment.  As we're deploying to AWS, we also employ separate stages per region.  This allows us to deploy to our Dev environment in both us-east-2 and us-east-1 at the same time.  You can use this approach to achieve high availability and/or disaster recovery.

Here's a link with more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops

Here's an simple example image of that type of
[Release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSstX.png).